# Issue with gridspec and colorbars

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to plot 5 3d plots in the form of a grid. I want the fifth sub-plot to be at the center of the last column. I have the following code below, but the formatting does not seem to be good at all as the colorbars are merging with the main plot ([img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJVd8.png)). I want all the plots the same size and color bars arranged in proper order. I apologize if this is an easy fix I am quite new to matplotlib.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(3, 3)
c = np.random.rand(3)

import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, [enter image description here][1]10), constrained_layout=True)
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(4, 4)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0:2], projection='3d')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,2:], projection='3d')
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1,0:2], projection='3d')
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1,2:], projection='3d')
ax5 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2,1:3], projection='3d')

axs = [ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4,ax5]

a1 = axs[0].scatter(x[:, 0], x[:, 1],x[:, 2],c= c)
plt.colorbar(a1, ax=axs[0])
a2 = axs[1].scatter(x[:, 0], x[:, 1],x[:, 2],c= c)
plt.colorbar(a2, ax=axs[1])
a3 = axs[2].scatter(x[:, 0], x[:, 1],x[:, 2],c= c)
plt.colorbar(a3, ax=axs[2])
a4 = axs[3].scatter(x[:, 0], x[:, 1],x[:, 2],c= c)
plt.colorbar(a4, ax=axs[3])
a5 = axs[4].scatter(x[:, 0], x[:, 1],x[:, 2],c= c)
plt.colorbar(a5, ax=axs[4])
gs.tight_layout(fig)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colorbars accompanying 3D axes are hard to position nicely with your approach. Here I create separate axes for each of the colorbars. To allow the plots and colorbars to occupy appropriate areas, I create more rows and columns in the `GridSpec()`, then specify the coverages of each axes. You can try running the provided code and adjust it to your needs.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(3, 3)
c = np.random.rand(3)

import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 9))

# create gridspec of 6 rows, 6 columns
# two additional columns are for plotting color bars, exclusively
# three additional rows for arranging subplots heights nicely in vertical direction
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(6, 6, width_ratios=[0.245, 0.245, 0.01, 0.245, 0.245, 0.01], \
                      height_ratios= [0.1, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4])
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:2, 0:2], projection='3d')
ax1a = fig.add_subplot(gs[1:2, 2:3])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:2, 3:5], projection='3d')
ax2a = fig.add_subplot(gs[1:2, 5:6])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2:4, 0:2], projection='3d')
ax3a = fig.add_subplot(gs[3:4, 2:3])
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2:4, 3:5], projection='3d')
ax4a = fig.add_subplot(gs[3:4, 5:6])
ax5 = fig.add_subplot(gs[4:6, 3:5], projection='3d')
ax5a = fig.add_subplot(gs[5:6, 5:6])

axs = [ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4,ax5]

a1 = axs[0].scatter(x[:, 0], x[:, 1],x[:, 2],c= c)
plt.colorbar(a1, cax=ax1a)

a2 = axs[1].scatter(x[:, 0], x[:, 1],x[:, 2],c= c)
plt.colorbar(a2, cax=ax2a)

a3 = axs[2].scatter(x[:, 0], x[:, 1],x[:, 2],c= c)
plt.colorbar(a3, cax=ax3a)

a4 = axs[3].scatter(x[:, 0], x[:, 1],x[:, 2],c= c)
plt.colorbar(a4, cax=ax4a)

a5 = axs[4].scatter(x[:, 0], x[:, 1],x[:, 2],c= c)
cb5 = plt.colorbar(a5, cax=ax5a)

gs.tight_layout(fig)
plt.show()
```

The output plot:

[image: array of 3d plot]